# What is the correct way to remove library using composer?

Tags: php, composer-php

I've been install 2 libraries into my php project. Now I want to remove on of them because I've install the wrong library (my bad). Is it okay if I just delete the folder ? If there is another way to do that correctly, please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the following command will remove the package from vendor (or wherever you install packages), composer.json and composer.lock. Change vendor/package appropriately.

```
composer remove vendor/package
```